# May I ask please why CSS is not taking effect on my HTML code?

Tags: html, css

[image: output]Trying out `CSS` style and would like to know reason of not getting effect of

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: calc(100% -4em);
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
}

.cacel_btn {
  width: 18px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="overlay">
  <img src="images/cancel_button.svg" class="cancel_btn" id="cancel_btn">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">home</a>
      <span>where you feel good</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">about us</a>
      <span>we are fantastic</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">service</a>
      <span>we are there for you</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">contact</a>
      <span>just come over</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there any problem with `grid system of CSS?`

My goal is to design the menu which should look like in attached image file.

Comment: Please add the image of your goal

Comment: Stackoverflow is preventing me to edit my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your html code there is the class "cacel_btn" instead of "cancel_btn".

Can you post your html-header? i want to see how you´ve linked the stylesheet.

Why are you using a class and an id with "cancel_btn"?

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Mega Menu</title>
</head>

Comment: thank you for your comment. I solved TYPO in CSS with cancel_bthn.

Comment: do do you habe any problems left now? is all working now?

Comment: please see, the output image as I have edited the question.